# Programmatically Change Database Table EntityFramework Model Object Refers to

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Question is in the title. Can we programmatically change the database table which an object in the Model class, like one below, refers to and continue to operate on the new table?

```
public class Word
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

This originally refers to "Words" table automatically in EntityFramework, is there a way to change it before/during runtime? If so, how?

**EDIT:**

I get all the string used in Views in the project from the database table, "Words", by their ID's. Now, what I want is, a user enters a new language to system, and a new table will be created, for example WordsEnglish. From then, the Word object will refer to WordEnglish, if user selects English as language.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: in the program, i will run sql query to create a new table, such as WordEnglish and Word class will continue to operate on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be desirable with a use case to better understand what you are trying to accomplish, but here goes...

In the [DbContext.OnModelCreating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method you can configure the model, e.g.

```
// Removes pluralization convention for all tables.
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

or

```
// Specific table name for Word Entity.
modelBuilder.Entity<Word>().ToTable("TableContainingWords");
```

If you are changing your model, [Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I havent found a way to truly dynamically extend an EF model at runtime.  Given what goes on in DB context inherited class, the use of generated views for performance and a model class approach, avoiding recompilation seems hard.  I have generated code, compiled and access this using assembly discovery approaches.  But this is all unsatisfactory from my viewpoint , so i have stopped investigating this path. Very clunky outcome.

Ironically the topic you provide as a use case for such a problem, is one that doesnt need dynamic EF in my view.

I have exactly the same use case, language specific look for messages/labels etc  Ie a language specific textpool.

Why not add language to the class/table.
Use a table or Enum for supported languages.
Use Language in the Textpool table/s

Use a different model class for presentation. (view model).
So you can present it the way like .

```
public class Word
{
     Guid ID {get;set;}                   // logical key is WordID + Language
     public int WordID { get; set; }      // implement with new id or 2 field key
     public Language Language {get;set;}    // see cultureInfo for more details 
     public bool IsMaster {get;set;}
     public string Text { get; set; }    // consider renaming due to reserved word implications
}

public class language
{
 int ID,
 String Lang
}

}
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation, but couldn't deal with viewing. Can you look at my other question in the link, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016199/how-to-deal-with-updatable-languages-and-their-words